# my select option not showing the images properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

My code:

```
<style>

    select#gender option[value="male"] {background-image:url(images/slidee3.jpg)}    


    select#gender option[value="female"] {background-image:url(images/slidee4.jpg);}


    select#gender option[value="others"] {background-image:url(images/slidee4.jpg);}


</style>


</head>

<body>
<select id="gender">

    <option  value="male" selected="selected">male</option>

    <option  value="female">female</option>

    <option  value="others">others</option>

</select>

</body>
```

Comment: I've got two questions: 1st - what do you mean by "not showing properly"? 2nd - who are the "others"?

Comment: @Y.Puzyrenko see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity

Comment: Hi,If i select a option from the drop box it not showing the image